# saving a variable filename in reportlab

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I keep getting an error " no attribute for string .pdf" with my code.  It works as a static filename, but not as a variable.  I have read the other examples on opening a filename, but none of them are inline like reportlab needs.

```
    testid = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    basename = str("cert")
    filename = "_".join([basename, testid])
    print filename
    canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename.pdf, pagesize=letter)
```

Comment: can you paste your exact error, or at least in which line it occures?

Comment: `filename.pdf` needs to be a string, so try `"filename.pdf"`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jamess.MUNCYTOOL\Desktop\GETTIN DER\standalonewindow.py", line 72, in P2PDF
    canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename.pdf, pagesize=letter)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pdf'

Comment: yes, handle is correct

Comment: Or, if `filename` gives the correct string, use `...Canvas(filename, ..`

Comment: "filename.pdf" will name the object filename.pdf, I need it to take the variable into account

Comment: You should invest some time on https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ :-)

Comment: it will look like cert_170508_091949.pdf

Comment: `filename + '.pdf'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example that fails on the last line, but should demonstrate the problem:

```
#!python2
#coding=utf-8

import datetime

testid = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
basename = str("cert")
filename = "_".join([basename, testid])
print filename
print "filename.pdf"
print filename.pdf
```

Output:

```
cert_170508_152300
filename.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print filename.pdf
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pdf'
```

You are passing a non-existing object(* as parameter, where a string is required.

(* actually, since filename exists (a string), it assumes you are trying to access its non-existing [attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) (just like the error says).

This should work:

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=letter)
```

---

This appends the .pdf suffix:

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename + '.pdf', pagesize=letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should combine your variable `filename` with the extension `.pdf`

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename+'.pdf', pagesize=letter)
```

if the variable doesn't contain the extension already

Comment: appreciate it everyone